# Why is my service-unit-file a file, but others are a directory?

Tags: systemd, services

I created a service-unit to run apache-httpd and it is working, but I am concerned that my service-unit configuration-file is a file, but the other items in the directory (/etc/systemd/system) are all directories, so my file looks like an anomaly:

[image]

It works, but why is my definition different than the others?

I used the [instructions at "Tech Guides" to create the service unit](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/centos/169/systemd-custom-service.html).

Answer (score 1):

The other directories you show are `.wants` and `.d` – they do not contain the entire service file (that will live in `/lib/systemd/system` for services installed through packages), but only modifications.

For example, if you run `systemctl edit (servicename).service` to make changes, maybe you want to set additional environment variables, you will automatically get a `/etc/systemd/system/servicename.d/override.conf` that contains your changes.

The intention of this is to have a clean separation of local changes made by the admin in `/etc/` and package-managed service definitions in `/lib/systemd/system` that may receive changes with package updates.

Comment: Minor nitpick, `.wants` aren’t for modifications ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Units are *both* files *and* directories.  The *complete* information about a unit is distributed over, and read from, both.

The mandatory files end in `.service`, `.target`, `.socket`, `.timer`, `.mount`, and so forth.

The optional directories end in `.service.d`, `.service.requires`, `.target.wants`, and so forth.  The ones that end in `.d` contain regular files.  The ones that end in `.wants` and `.requires` contain symbolic links.  For details, read the `systemd.unit` manual.

In your case, the file and (currently non-existent) directory are both under `/etc/systemd`.  You, the local administrator, are the source of both.  In the case of the other units, the file is somewhere else such as under `/usr/lib/systemd` and the directories are under `/etc/systemd`.  This reflects the fact that the file part is supplied by a software package and the directory parts have been created as the results of local administrator choices and modifications (such as modifying the `Wants` setting of a unit in order to enable some other unit).

systemd's model is that stuff under `/usr/lib/systemd` and `/usr/local/lib/systemd` is package-supplied, stuff under `/run/systemd` is created on the fly whilst the system is running, and stuff under `/etc/systemd` is determined by the local system administrator.  The regular files, directories, and symbolic links in all four areas (which can involve more than just a single `system` subdirectory, again for details of which see the manual) are synthesized into the complete unit information, with rules about what takes precedence over what.